# Kentico 10 - Failing PCI Scan XXS

Tags: xss, kentico

We are still on Kentico 10 and failed a PCI scan. Results said XXS vulnerabilities. Not completely understanding [Kentico Documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/securing-websites/developing-secure-websites/cross-site-scripting-xss) on how to resolve this. Tested with alert(1) in Search box and it executed with a 1 in a message box popup.
Already updated Web Config file with recommendations.  Documentation lists the following as ways to avoid, but I am not sure where to do this. In the CMS itself? On the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you keyed a script call into your Search Box and received the popup that means you need to encode text being entered. HTMLEncode is probably the first one I'd do. Do that in the code-behind before you save it to the system or use the input for anything.

Comment: We fixed the Search Box issue via a few lines in the web.config file, however we still fail because we have an older version of JQuery.  Trustwave specifically looks for which version of JQuery you have, which we can not upgrade without breaking the CMS.  Only solution is to upgrade our CMS version or choose a new CMS.  Our director is exploring both options.

Comment: Well I can understand the JQuery specific issue. I had the same issue with Sitecore & Qualys Web Application Scanning. The Kentico docs say best practice is to avoid using the built-in JQuery library, due to future potential of breaking sites. 

I'm not sure if we implemented a custom JQuery library myself, only 3 weeks on the job. But is that a potential option for you? https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/best-practices-for-customization - bottom of the article.